# Returning non Base64 encoded data from API gateway Lambda proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a API Gateway Lambda proxy integration. I am calling a third party API from the lambda and which returns a jpg image. When returning this image to API gateway from lambda with image/jpg header, I am getting "Malformed Lambda proxy response" error from API gateway unless we do base64 encoding.

Is there any way to passthrough the response without doing base64 encoding?

I tried with adding image/jpg,  application/octect-stream etc to binary media settings in API gateway but no luck

Comment: I believe you need to perform base64 encoding, there's no way around it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html. One approach I was considering is using the `HTTP_PROXY` integration with the Lambda function HTTP URL. In theory (I've never tried it) it should work, but I see no way to use the `AWS_IAM ` auth type on the function URL.